# Override blog layout to display articles under subcategory headings

Tags: joomla-3.x, overrides, subcategories

What I'm trying to do is create a category blog layout that will display the title of a category, followed by subcategories with the articles of those subcategories (full article, not just it's title) displayed directly after, like so:

TOP LEVEL CATEGORY

- Subcategory 1

  - Subcategory 1 Article 1
  - Subcategory 1 Article 2
  - Subcategory 1 Article 3
- Subcategory 2

  - Subcategory 2 Article 1
  - Subcategory 2 Article 2
  - Subcategory 2 Article 3

I don't think this should be too difficult to do, but I haven't been able to find a simple solution. I've tried to call the items template:

```
echo $this->loadTemplate('item');
```

within blog_children.php, but I get a fatal error: Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object. Has anyone accomplished this or have any advice?

Answer (score -1):

try , even if you haven't overriden it, to copy the default_item template into your template HTML folder.

To get to this result, you have to override the initial com_content templates of, let's say, blog. The overrides you do are to be put in your templates html folder (/templates/my_template/html/com_content/ to be specific). when you do so, it looks in that same folder for every subtemplate included. Like, for instance, blog_item, or default_item, or whatever according to the layout you are overriding. if it can't find it, you get a Fatal error, though I don't remember which one.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not seeing a default_item file, only default_articles and default_children in my components/com_content/views/category/tmpl. Is it hiding somewhere else?